# Using getDefaultSharedPreferences in a method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

So I am using getdefaultsharedpreferences in a method called onLoadFinish (it's from a pdf library from android).
Here's the code:

```
    public void onLoadFinish(DocumentState.OPEN state) {
    //some irrelevant code here
    SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                String text = pref.getString("example_list","");
                int foo = Integer.parseInt(text);
                goToPage(foo);
    //some irrelevant code there
}
```

So the main task of the code is to get a value from my example_list preference (a string), turn it into an integer and put this integer into my `goTopage();`, which makes the app jump to a certain page in my pdf document.

The problem is this part:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())
```

getActivity isn't working. I have tried getApplicationContext() aswell. What should be in the brackets of getDefaultSharedPreferences()?

Comment: what do you mean by `getActivity isn't working`?

Comment: "Can't resolve method 'getActivity()'"

Comment: are you calling it inside the fragment?

Comment: No, its Quite complicated: i have an activity where i call the simplereaderview (From the PDF library). That means I have to do the gotopage thing in this simplereaderview activity, in the public void onloadfinish to be exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getDefaultSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) expects an instance of `Context` class. [getActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) method is declared in the [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) class, so, unless your `onLoadFinish` method is declared in any `Fragment` successor, you can't use it. Per your comments, if I understood you correctly, `onLoadFinish` is declared inside [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). If so, you can just use `this` keyword to pass the context, because `Activity` is a successor of `Context`. If this method is declared in another class, you should pass context to it, via constructor injection, for example.

**EDIT** Example of providing context via constructor injection.

Let's say you have the following interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void myAction();
}
```

And you have a class, which implements it and requires an instance of `Context` to do the work:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    private WeakReference<Context> mContext;

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        this.mContext = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void myAction() {
        Context ctx = mContext.get();
        if (ctx != null){
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Context` instance is injected via constructor and we don't keep a strong reference to the context (actually it depends on specific needs). This class can be used inside `Activity` in the following way:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
```

Or inside fragment:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(getActivity());
```

Comment: Alright, when I'm using "this", android studio says, "this", cannot be applied to my "SimpleDocumentReader"class and wants me to make SimpleDocumentReader extend "Android.content.Context". Should I do this?

Comment: @just_deko are you sure that `SimpleDocumentReader` is activity? can you show the signature of the class where you implemented `SimpleDocumentReaderListener` interface?

Comment: `public class SimpleDocumentReader implements ReaderListener {}` do you mean this?

Comment: @just_deko yes. Looks like `SimpleDocumentReader` is not activity and just a plain class. So you should inject context via constructor, for example

Comment: Could you link me to a tutorial or something of that kind to give me an idea how to do this? Sorry, I am still a beginner in java programming and this is my first app.

Comment: @just_deko I've added a simple example. This is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android where you can read more about the context

Comment: So, I've tried to apply this to my case. replaced MyClass with SimpleDocumentreader and MyAction with onLoadFinish and inserted the code there. No errors whatsoever but the the app isn't jumping to the page I want, meaning ctx is null. Have I forgot something?

Comment: @just_deko i don't know how do you use `SimpleDocumentReader` inside your code. I've used `WeakReference` in my example, which means, that `Activity` may be garbage collected. You can try to use plain strong reference without wrapping into `WeakReference`, also please read about activity/fragment lifecycle

Comment: As this is a pdf library, I am using the code in my Activity (where I display the pdf document) like this: `SimpleDocumentReader v = SimpleReaderFactory.createSimpleViewer(this, null);
        v.openUrl("myurlhere", "123456");` (if that helps)

Comment: @just_deko per https://plugpdf.com/devrefs/android/classcom_1_1epapyrus_1_1plugpdf_1_1_simple_reader_factory.html I can say, that you don't provide the listener (it's `null` per you code). Create class `MyClass implements SimpleDocumentReaderListener` and provide its instance as the second parameter

Comment: the second parameter for what? `createSimpleViewer`?

Comment: @just_deko yes, docs clearly states, that second parameter is `listener The SimpleDocumentViewerListener instance.`

Answer (score 0):

PreferenceManager should be used with a PreferenceActivity.

Just use `context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: your first statement is wrong, it can be used anywhere, it just requires an instance of `Context` class.

Answer (score 0):

[getDefaultSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context))  required your application context a parameter,
Try this,

```
    public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    {
    ......
    .......
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyActivity.this);
    ......
    ......

    }
```